# std::function with non-static member functions

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2010

i'm trying to understand a concept and an error. what's wrong with this?

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::function<void(int)> testFunc(&A::func);
    }

private:
    void func(int) {}
}
```

my question, is it possible to create any sort of object that is able to call a member of a specific instance where std::function acts like a member function pointer, except without the wacky type definition that can't be used as function parameters in inheriting classes. for example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
         index[WM_CREATE] = &A::close;
         index[WM_DESTROY] = &A::destroy;
    }

protected:
    map<UINT msg, void (A::*)(HWND, UINT , WPARAM, LPARAM)> index;
    void close(HWND,UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    void destroy(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        index[WM_CREATE] = &B::create; // error because it's not a pointer of type A::*
    }
private:
    void create(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

};
```

I'm thinking i'm on the right track of using std::functions like so:

```
class A
{
public:             //         Gigantic stl error with these two
    A()             //                         |
    {               //                         V
         index[WM_CREATE] = std::function<void(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM>(&A::close);
         index[WM_DESTROY] = std::function<void(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM>(&A::destroy);
    }

protected:
    map<UINT msg, std::function<void(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)> > index;
    void close(HWND,UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    void destroy(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
};

class B : public A
{
public:                    //               and this one
    B()                    //                     |
    {                      //                     V
        index[WM_CREATE] = std::function<void(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)>(&B::create);
    }
private:
    void create(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

};
```

if someone could explain what these giant cryptic errors mean and how to fix them, i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: When you say "call a member of a specific instance where `std::function` acts like a member function pointer", does that mean that the specific instance is specified at the time of creation of the `std::function` object? This is what the `void(int)` signature suggests, but then the result object would not act "like a member function pointer", it would act like a callback / functor. If on the other hand you meant that the resulting `std::function` object really acts like a member function pointer, then the signature is wrong (e.g. it could be `void(A&, int)` instead). Which is it?

Comment: not sure what a callback/ functor is, but it kinda sounds like we're differentiating between a static functions and a non-static functions, and i want it to be a non-static function. They're handlers so they need to be able to manipulate only this instances members. As in the examples, i want that function to be called when the corresponding map index is passed in. simply, i wish to do this: index[WM_CREATE](hwnd, msg, lparam, wparam); and the only way i can think to do that is store function pointers or something similar there.I can't do actual pointers though because it breaks inheritance :(

Comment: Can't you use [`std::mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) instead?

Comment: never heard of it. might you be able to post in an answer what it's use in this might be?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that a member function requires not only a function pointer, but a pointer to the calling object.  In other words, member functions have an additional implicit argument that is the pointer to the calling object.

To set a member function to a std::function, you need to use std::bind like this:

```
std::function<void(int)> testFunc(std::bind(&A::func, this, _1));
```

This binds the this pointer of the current A instance to the function so it has the function pointer and the object instance, which is enough information to properly call the function.  The _1 argument indicates that the first explicit argument will be provided when the function is called.

Comment: error C2065: '_1' : undeclared identifier.
I called it like `HandlerIndex[WM_CREATE] = std::function<void(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)>(std::bind(&BasicWindow::MsgCreate, this, _1))`

Comment: You need a placeholder for every argument, so it would be: `std::function<void(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)>(std::bind(&BasicWindow::MsgCreate, this, _1, _2, _3, _4))`

Comment: ah gotcha, i'll try it when i'm home in a bit.

Comment: now i get unknown identifier for all 4 of those last parameters. just underscore1 right?

Comment: Yeah, one underscore.  You may need to use `std::placeholders::_1` and so on for each argument.

Comment: boom, works like a friggen charm. you've just solved all my problems, and i actually understand the reason why it wouldn't work before. being a non-static member func, it has that silent this argument that was making it think there was one parameter too many. the bind function is incredibly useful if it can do some of the stuff i think it can do. Anyway, in the end, that single function call got rediculously long, so i'll just do a macro to simplify the process a bit.

Answer (score 2):

With c++11 you can also use lambdas which are slightly easier to read than `std::bind`:

```
index[WM_CREATE] = [this](HWND h, UINT u, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
  create(h, u, w, l);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> my question, is it possible to create any sort of object that is able to call a member of a specific instance

In this case the only information that is missing is in fact what specific instance the `std::function` object should use: `&A::func` can't be used on its own (for instance `(this->*&A::func)(0)` uses `&A::func` with instance `*this`). Try:

```
std::function<void(int)> testFunc = std::bind(&A::func, this);
```

(Be careful that `std::bind(&A::func, *this)` and `std::bind(&A::func, this)` have slightly different semantics.)